# Complex HTML grid created dynamically given a list of shapes

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Input : I start with a list of squares and rectangles. There are 4 possible sizes (1x1, 1x2, 2x1, and 2x2 ). The list might be any length and any combination of the 4 shapes. [image]

Problem: I would like to stack all of these shapes into a container of width 4 with no dead space. Like Tetris but the shapes fit into the ceiling of the container instead of the floor

I've thought of 3 approaches each with it's own problem.

1. Using absolutes (only viable solution so far but I hope to not have to do this) - Problem is that I would like this to dynamically resize and collapse like bootstrap does which would turn this into a complex solution where I think there may be a simple one.
2. Using bootstrap grids. - Problem is that in some situations there may be no defined columns or rows. See Image1 for example where this is a problem.( If someone could define Image1 in bootstrap I could probably take it from there )
   Image1:  [image: Image1]
3. Using floats - Creates dead space. In the example below. The 2nd small red square should fall below the 1st and to the left of the blue rectangle, but in this example it falls to the right of the blue rectangle.
   [image]

Stipulation: The shapes should be ROUGHLY display in the order they appear in the list, because those are the shapes that should be seen first. Smaller shapes will obviously need to be moved forward to fill gaps. BASICALLY, I could find a solution by manipulation the shapes into groups but since they are in order of priority I can't use this solution.

Any comments, ideas, questions and conversation are welcomed and appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: It could be worth looking at https://masonry.desandro.com/ or https://jquery-mosaic.tin.cat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you can achieve it with bootstrap, but here is heuristic which works pretty well (of course as any heuristic you can find edge cases with strange results)

```js
// special handling for 3rd shape to avoid some edge cases
function s3(i, j, r, n) {
    if (j == 0 || j == 3) return true;
    if (r[i+1][j-1]!=0) return true;
    if (n == 3 && r[i][j+1]==0 && r[i+1][j+1]==0) return true;
    return false;
}
// returns true if shape can be drawn in this position
function canFit(s, i, j, r, f, n) {
    switch (s) {
    case 1: return r[i][j]==0;
    case 2: return j<3 && r[i][j]==0 && r[i][j+1]==0;
    case 3: return r[i][j]==0 && r[i+1][j]==0 && s3(i, j, r, n);
    case 4: return j<3 && r[i][j]==0 && r[i][j+1]==0 && r[i+1][j]==0 && r[i+1][j+1]==0;
    }
    return false;
}
// determines color of the shape
function clr(s) {
    switch(s) {
    case 1: return 'a';
    case 2: return 'b';
    case 3: return 'c';
    case 4: return 'd';
    }
}
// main function to use
function drawBox(oa) {
    var a = [];
    var f = [0,0,0,0];
    for (var k=0; k<oa.length; k++) {
        f[oa[k]-1]++;
        a.push([oa[k], k]);
    }

    var r = [];

    document.write('<div class="box">');
    var idx = 0;
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var h = [];
    while (a.length > 0) {
        if (idx == a.length) break;
        if (i >= r.length) r[i] = [0, 0, 0, 0];
        if (i+1 >= r.length) r[i+1] = [0, 0, 0, 0];

        var s = a[idx][0];
        var op = a[idx][1];
        if (canFit(s, i, j, r, f, idx+1<a.length?a[idx+1][0]:-1)) {
            switch (s) {
            case 1: h.push([s, op, j==0]); f[0]--; r[i][j]=1; break;
            case 2: h.push([s, op, j==0]); f[1]--; r[i][j]=r[i][j+1]=2; break;
            case 3: h.push([s, op, j==0 || (j==1 && r[i+1][j-1]!=0)]); f[2]--; r[i][j]=r[i+1][j]=3; break;
            case 4: h.push([s, op, j==0 || (j==1 && r[i+1][j-1]!=0)]); f[3]--; r[i][j]=r[i][j+1]=r[i+1][j]=r[i+1][j+1]=4; break;
            }
            a.splice(idx, 1); idx=0;
            while (r[i][j]!=0 && j<4) j++;
        } else
            idx++;
        if (j == 4) {
            if (h.length > 0) {
                for (var k=0; k<h.length && h[k][2]; k++)
                    document.write('<div class="'+clr(h[k][0])+' l">' + h[k][1] + '</div>');
                for (var k=h.length-1; k>=0 && !h[k][2]; k--)
                    document.write('<div class="'+clr(h[k][0])+' r">' + h[k][1] + '</div>');
                h = [];
            }
            do {
                i++;
                if (i+1 >= r.length) r[i+1] = [0, 0, 0, 0];
                for (j=0; j<4; j++) if (r[i][j] == 0) break;
            } while (r[i][j] != 0);
        }
    }
    document.write('</div>');
}

// main calls with sample arrays
drawBox([3,1,2,2,3,4,1,2]);document.write('<br><br>');
drawBox([1,3,3,3,3,4,3,1]);document.write('<br><br>');
drawBox([1,1,3,3,4,3,3,1,1]);document.write('<br><br>');
drawBox([1,1,3,3,1,3,3,1,1,2,1]);document.write('<br><br>');
drawBox([1,1,3,3,1,3,4,1,1,1]);document.write('<br><br>');
drawBox([1,1,3,3,1,3,4,1,3]);document.write('<br><br>');
```

```css
.box {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ffa0ff;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.b {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ffffa0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.c {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #a0a0ff;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.d {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ffa0a0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.l {
    float: left;
}
.r {
    float: right;
}
```

I suppose it is quite easy to update it for cases with wrong results

Comment: That looks awesome! Really appreciate the thorough answer and complete code. I am in the middle of an approach but will probably use your approach because it seems more universal. Thank you